# X509Certificate2(certpath) - The given paths format is not supported

Tags: c#, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

When I am sending an SSL certificate over httpwebrequest I am getting an error  - The given paths format is not supported. Here is the code.

```cs
string cerpath = @"c:\sagar\cert.cer";
string url = @"C:\localhost\";

Httpwebrequest req = (Httpwebrequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

X509Cetificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(cerPath);

//Raises error The given paths format is not supported

req.ClientCertificate.Add(cert);
```

Comment: are you sure `url` value should be `@"C:\localhost\"`

Comment: Specified url is just sample url. Original is different

Comment: can a simiple `File.Open` is able to read it? is cert initialized? where it fails?

Comment: It fails on the line where i pass the cerificate file.

Comment: I.e. X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(cerPath)

Comment: I tested it on my PC and I don't get such error, check there are no white spaces in the certificate path. and file format is correct

Comment: I stored path in web.config, after getting it value in variable it print same path as i mentioned in web.config in immidiate window. But when i copy the same path from variable and paste it to textpad, the path is preceded by '?' character. It print in textpad as "?F:\Sagar\Ssldoc\maincert.crt

Comment: as I have said there was a whitespace character.

Comment: Yes.. you were right. Now i am getting bad gateway exception when on req.GetInputStream function